# Properties of Normal Numbers

Tags: number-theory, lebesgue-measure

I found these two properties of normal numbers on [the Wikipedia page for "normal numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Properties), but I can't find any other source for them. I was wondering if they were in fact true, and if somebody could give me a hint on how to prove them.

1. Any number is the product of two  absolutely normal numbers.
2. If $x$ is normal in base $b$, and $q \neq 0$ is a rational number, then $ x\cdot q$ is normal in base $b$.

I was thinking that 1 could sort of follow from Borel's proof that almost every real number is normal. However I'm not sure about the second.